# How to add Remote virtual environment python interpreter in pycharm along with vagrant

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

I am running pycharm in my windows box, while my Django project is running inside vagrant ubuntu box, I am pulling all my project files to window pycharm along with the remote python interpreter(which is OS default). The problem is I am not able to setup the remote virtualenv python interpreter.

How to set up remote virtualenv python interpreter in pycharm ? not the default OS one.
[image]